# Mailchimp: get rid of mcsv.net from header

Tags: email, gmail, mailchimp, email-headers

In my **Mailchimp** account I successfully verified my domain and I also authenticated it with valid **DKIM** and **SPF** records (the domain is only an example):
[image: mailchimp domain verification]

When sending campaings I set the From address to be info@mywebsite.com.
But headers of received email (Gmail) show:

- **from**: info@mywebsite.com
- **reply-to**: info@mywebsite.com
- **mailed-by**: mail70.atl91.mcsv.net
- **signed by**: mywebsite.com

Is it possible to show mywebsite.com also for the **mailed by** header?

Answer (score 2):

mail70.atl91.mcsv.net is maybe the hostname of mailchimp this is why it goes in the header of the email and gmail automatically identifies that this email is coming form this from domain and there is no way to chnage that.

In simpler words this is not possible to remove mail70.atl91.mcsv.net.

If you wish to remove it you will have to steup your own mail server which is normally not very difficult